# ViewWillAppear is not calling at the dismisal of modalview controller

Tags: ios, delegates

I have two class A  and B .

```
class A{ 

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) { . 

print("")
}

     let myPost = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Completed") as! Completed

        myPost.transitioningDelegate = self as? UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate
        myPost.modalPresentationStyle = .custom

        self.present(myPost, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
class B{ . 

 dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Here I am presenting class B from class A. But when I am dismissing class B the viewWillApper (in class A) is not calling. How to achive this?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and post real, relevant code that actually replicates your issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can use viewdidload() or awakefromnib() to be called when you present other contollers like A from B or B from 
A

Comment: Hi Mayank in my case when i am comming  back to B to A  none of these ,viewdidload() or awakefromnib() is working

Comment: When you dismiss a controller the one behind has been loaded already. So if you want to perform any function on dismissal you can put it in the dismiss method or can use segue or push controller then view didLoad() will be called